# how to create view instance knowing its id?

Tags: android, view

I would like to create instances of all my views in application once and during execution pass proper view to Activity.setContentView() - by reference not by id.
So - how to properly create view knowing its id?

Additional question:
How is view instance created when I pass id into Activity.setContentView?
Every time I call setContentView new instance is created?

regards for all

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? My disclaimer is that holding instances for ALL your views in one activity is excessive and unnecessary. You should probably split the functionality of your code into multiple activities and have one layout associated with each.

If you *must* use multiple views within the same activity, this type of behavior is probably better done within your layout file (putting multiple views in your layout, then showing/hiding them in your code).

That being said, what you'll need is the [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) class. Inflate the layout and do what you want with it. If you're looking for a specific view within this layout, use the `findViewByID()` method on that inflated layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
View v = ll.findViewByID(R.id.view_name);
//Do stuff with view or layout
```

Comment: Do You suggest that in situation when application (lets say: game) has multiple screens (main menu,game,options/hall of fame) they all should be put as views into single layout? How to design that layout properly in designer knowing that finally each 1-st level child will spread to whole screen?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you keep multiple views into a single layout. I'd suggest keeping them as separate layouts (different xml files) and use them with their own independent activities. i.e. you'd have an activity for the Main Menu, a different activity for the options, different activity for the hall of fame, etc. Doing this will minimize the amount of memory that each activity will take, making it easier for the Android system to manage properly.